# определить http по tcp пакету

Tags: http, сеть, tcp-ip

По википедии и в сниффере wireshark в IP-пакете есть явное указание на протокол передачи (например tcp). А для tcp я не нашел ни в гугле, ни в сниффере. Как можно определить http протокол, имея tcp пакет?

Comment: Если этот tcp-пакет случайно выдран случайным куском из потока, то скорее всего никак

Comment: Явно в пакете протокол не указан, но т.к. http-протокол достаточно открытый, то по заголовкам вверху пакета (если пакет целый) можно определить (вычислить) что это http.

Comment: (ну так на всякий случай) "по умолчанию" для портов 80 используется http протокол. В 99,9% случаев порт 80 (порт в пакете видно) - протокол http. Но настроить туда другой протокол не запрещено.